# what is not equal to in spark.sql()

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm practicing using `spark.sql()` functions for pyspark. When I use the not equal functions in spark I can't seem to use `<> != Not` to do complex queries.

Sample query:

```
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|               Party|       Handle|               Tweet|
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|Today, Senate Dem...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @WinterHavenSu...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @NBCLatino: .@...|
|Congress has allo...|         null|                null|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @NALCABPolicy:...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @Vegalteno: Hu...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @EmgageActionF...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|Hurricane Maria l...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @Tharryry: I a...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @HispanicCaucu...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @RepStephMurph...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @AllSaints_FL:...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|.@realDonaldTrump...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|Thank you to my m...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|We paid our respe...|
|Sgt Sam Howard - ...|         null|                null|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @WinterHavenSu...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|Meet 12 incredibl...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @wildlifeactio...|
|            Democrat|RepDarrenSoto|RT @CHeathWFTV: K...|
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+

spark.sql("""select Party from tweets_tempview where Party <>'Democrat' or 'Republican' """).show(20,False)
```

Error Message:

```
"cannot resolve '((NOT (tweets_tempview.`Party` = 'Democrat')) OR 'Republican')' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '((NOT (tweets_tempview.`Party` = 'Democrat')) OR 'Republican')' (boolean and string).; line 1 pos 40;\n'Project ['Party]\n+- 'Filter (NOT (Party#98 = Democrat) || Republican)\n   +- SubqueryAlias `tweets_tempview`\n      +- Relation[Party#98,Handle#99,Tweet#100] csv\n"
```

What is the spark sql function to get both where clause values to work?

Comment: IIUC you want to exclude both parties?  `... where Party not in ('Democrat', 'Republican')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare to two strings using a single `<>` operation. Either use:

```
where Party <> 'Democrat' and Party <> 'Republican'
```

Or use this, as suggested in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66749682/what-is-not-equal-to-in-spark-sql/66749877#comment117993600_66749682)

```
where Party not in ('Democrat', 'Republican')
```